# Dynamically Change TextView Background color in onclicklistener in android

Tags: android

If we click any of the Textview within a Listview, background color should have to change and onclick release, it should have to change to transparent color in android.How to achieve this in onclicklistener of Textview in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the text view's background to a [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)